# Liaisons between “pas” and a vowel

Tags: liaisons

In the sentence, “Il n'y est pas allé”, is there a liaison between *s* in *pas* and *a* in *allé* or can it be omitted?

Comment: You can and can not pronounce it, but it gives a more professional impression while uttering the liaison.